# Fast method to match geospatial datasets in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, geospatial, geopandas, dask-delayed

I have a set of 2000 geospatial points (lon/lat), which I need to match with several other geospatial datasets (I am using Geopandas GeoDataFrames). I am using the sklearn BallTree function to find the neighbors within a certain radius of each point (in the function below, point is one of the 2000 points and right_gdf is the dataset that I need to get the neighbors from).

I am currently using a for-loop to loop through all of the 2000 points and find the neighbors for each of them. However, depending on the size of right_gdf, this can take a long time. I am sure there is a way to speed this process up, potentially with parallel computing, but I am struggling to find it. I tried to use Dask delayed to parellelise the loop (see code below) but somehow this takes even longer than the simple for loop.

```
# Function that finds a point's neighbors within a certain radius
def neighbours_radius(point, right_gdf, R=1):

  # Create tree from the right gdf (use haversine for lat/lon coordinates)
  tree = BallTree(right_gdf, leaf_size=40, metric='haversine')

  # Find indices of all neighbors within R
  indices = tree.query_radius(point, r=r)[0]

return indices


# Function that loops through the 2000 points
def knn_gpd(right_gdf, R=75):

  # Load the gdf with the 2000 points
  base = gpd.read_file(...)

  # Empty list to fill in the indices of the neighbors
  neighbors = []

  # Loop through the points and find the neighbors within R.
  for i in range(len(base)):
      point = base.iloc[i:i+1,:]
      ind = neighbours_radius(point, right_gdf, R=R)

      # append index lists
      neighbors.append(ind)

return neighbors


# Function that loops through the 2000 points with Dask delayed
def knn_gpd_dask(right_gdf, R=75):

  # Load the gdf with the 2000 points
  base = gpd.read_file(...)

  # Empty list to fill in the indices of the neighbors
  neighbors = []

  # Loop through the points and find the neighbors within R.
  for i in range(len(base):
    point = base.iloc[i:i+1,:]
    ind = delayed(neighbours_radius)(point, right_gdf, R=R)

    # append index list
    neighbors.append(ind)
  
  result = compute(neighbors)

return result
```

Can anyone help me speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you profile your code, I suspect you will find that creating the `BallTree` is taking up most of the time, because you are creating it 2000 times. You should try to create it only once, like this for example:

```
# Function that loops through the 2000 points
def knn_gpd(right_gdf, R=75):

  # Load the gdf with the 2000 points
  base = gpd.read_file(...)

  # Create tree from the right gdf (use haversine for lat/lon coordinates)
  tree = BallTree(right_gdf, leaf_size=40, metric='haversine')

  # Empty list to fill in the indices of the neighbors
  neighbors = []

  # Loop through the points and find the neighbors within R.
  for i in range(len(base)):
      point = base.iloc[i:i+1,:]

      # Find indices of all neighbors within R
      indices = tree.query_radius(point, r=r)[0]

      # append index lists
      neighbors.append(indices )

return neighbors
```